# How I can sum two value in python by defining function and in which user give input in print level code must be in four lines only

Tags: python-3.x

How i can get sum by using furcation in python cod emus be in four line
def addtwo(a,b):
sum=a+b
return sum:
print(input(addtwo))
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChtT9.png

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

def add(a,b):

```
    return a+b
```

a,b=map(int,input().split())

print(add(a,b))

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also, please familiarize yourself with how to correctly format code in posts. See the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.